# how to retain a core data string which gets autoreleased

Tags: ios, instruments, dealloc

I have a modal object which has several string and one of the strings always gets released. Using malloc breakpoint and instruments zombie detection i found out which is the object. But now not sure what to do about it since i'm using ARC

I have put some code below

Core Data Managed Object

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * newExVal;
```

accessing it in two places

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     ABC *abc = [abcList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     int newCnt = [abc.newExVal intValue];
}
```

and similarly in

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
     ABC *abc = [abcList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     int newCnt = [abc.newExVal intValue];
}
```

It crashes in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`and not in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. I'm aware that `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath` . What should i do to make sure this string is not released.

**EDIT:**  `Error message -[CFString intValue]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x98707e0`

I'm assigning the value in the xml parser like this

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

    if (ord_newExp) {
        ord_newExp = NO;
         orderList.newExceptionVal =  string;
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so, post it. What are you trying to do with abcList.newExVal? abcList is an array, I presume, so you can't use the dot notation like that. Also, is newExVal the same thing as newExceptionVal?

Comment: My bad.. did not put the right code. Now i have corrected it.. i have put the error message

Comment: is newExVal part of your model? If not make it at least a transient part and show where and how you assign a value to it.

Comment: yes its a part of the model. Edited.

Comment: If you are on ARC, the attribute of newExVal should be `nonatomic, strong`.

Comment: i'm using ARC.. its still comes as retain.

Comment: You should not be using strong or retain for NSStrings, or any other class which is the front end for a class cluster which can contain mutable subclasses. Use copy. And obvious question, if it's actually an integer, why are you storing it on the managed object as a string?

Comment: I'm generating the managedObjectmodel. this is auto generated by xcode for that particular object model. I tried storing it as an nsnumber but still gives the same issue.